# Can't download document from library

Tags: document-library, remote-blob-storage, file

We have document library which contains about 2,5k SCORM packages (about 100GB total) for teachers. This files are relatively big and in *.zip format, so we decided to enable RBS on content databse which is used for this site collection (only one site collection in this database).

Everything was working fine, but suddenly users reported that they can't download any package. If one tries to download a copy of document, error is displayed that this file can't be opened. And in ULS we can find:

```
Nie można otworzyć pliku "<file_name>".
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Nie można otworzyć pliku "<file_name>".    
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAsStream(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Boolean bHonorLevel, Byte iLevel, OpenBinaryFlags grfob, String bstrEtagNotMatch, String& pEtagNew, String& pContentTagNew)
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAsStream(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Boolean bHonorLevel, Byte iLevel, OpenBinaryFlags grfob, String bstrEtagNotMatch, String& pEtagNew, String& pContentTagNew)
```

Given that message, I have no clue where problem may be and how I could eventually repair this issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem on SQL server. Somehow volume which is shared between failover cluster nodes for stroing RBS data was down. After bringing it up, everything started to work as expected.